# Setting up a Node.js js server with Angular 2 frontend using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, ibm-cloud

I want to host my web application on IBM Bluemix and want Angular 2 using Typescript as the frontend and Node.js as the backend. How do I set up the server and connect it to the frontend and mainly, which transpiler do I use to transpiler the ts files?

Comment: Have you already explored the Mean stack? http://mean.io/

Comment: I started learning Angular 2 (this is my first frontend framework), I have seen people link their Node to Angular frontend but never people using Angular 2 and Typescript. The problem being that Typescript needs a transpiler to convert to JavaScript. As a beginner I am having problems setting up the transpiler with the node back end and all. I just want to know a good way to set it up.

Comment: Hi GrumpyDwarf97, I guess the answers in this thread might help you. It is certainly helping me to get my Angular2 stuff run on Bluemix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594760/does-bluemix-support-angular-2

Answer (score 2):

There is a continuously updated git project with a sample application that ships with Node.js, Angular2 and TypeScript, configured to use in development (hot reloading) and production mode. You'll have it up and running in 10 minutes.

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you very much for your starter kit, it does run on my local machine immediately without any problem (except for some npm warning about deprecated packages), but have you ever tried to build, deploy and run it on bluemix? I tried very hard with the officical angularjs 2 tutorial (the hero app tutorial), "cf push" -ed my app to my bluemix space (where there is a node-js runtime 4.2.2 available), added some bluemix-specific configuration files, but it simply does not get built or run. Have you tried with your own starter on bluemix?

Comment: Hi Matt, I saw that you also provided docker support files in your angular2 starter kit. I'm not familiar with Docker, but Bluemix does offer the Docker possibility. Could you please also add some simple instruction on how to get the whole thing run on Bluemix, with or without Docker? Thank you very much for reading my question.

Comment: Hey Nicole, I'm not a contributor of the starter kit, we just use it within our company, and not in production yet. I'm sorry I can't help you out with Bluemix or other cloud integration scenarios since we run it on our own infrastructure.

Comment: I don't see node backend anywhere in there. That's just an Angular starter kit, hardly an answer to this question.