# How do I deploy an Angular 2 app on Bluemix?

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud

I have tried to deploy a few basic Angular 2 projects on Bluemix and got only errors after the build.

Did anybody manage to have Angular 2 working on Bluemix? In that case, did you set anything specific in package.json file?

I couldn't get over this error message:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "run" "tsc:w"
```

Comment: We have an Angular 2 app on Pivotal Cloud Foundry, which is based on the same platform as BlueMix; rather than faff around with Node build packs and NPM dependencies, we build for prod then push the resulting HTML and compiled JS to the static buildpack. I've a simple example here: https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/248731. Please don't revert legitimate edits.

Comment: please refer the answer on post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123329/10179262

Answer (score 5):

It would be great to post a sample or a link to your source code. But from the two log lines it sounds like you are trying to deploy the Angular 2 app including the Node.js tooling it comes with.

As pointed by the previous comment, you'd rather build your Angular 2 app and deploy the resulting files, keeping the Node.js tooling for your local development.

I've put together a sample doing just that https://github.com/l2fprod/bluemix-hello-angular2. Consider it an even simpler version of the above example.

It is a new project generated with the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli), then I did the minimum required changes to deploy the build to Bluemix.

Comment: Hi Frederic, thank you very much for your solution, it helped me get the hello-world of Angular2 running on Bluemix! 

I had some problems while trying out. But found solution from internet: In the instruction of your README file, the 6th or 7th step, after installing the  Angular-cli, an "ng init" should run, in order to load some libraries which are necessary for "ng build". Or you may want to update the "script" section of your package.json, to include this "ng init".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to deploy an angular2 app to Bluemix.

1. You can export your static files and push the dist folder along with manifest.yml file
   https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html
2. You can deploy your app in a Docker container with your nginx.conf file

I highly recommend deploying the app in a Docker container. It will give you more freedom in development.

Here is a post I find really useful.
http://heidloff.net/article/angular-2-bluemix-docker-nginx

I hope this can help

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer, because an Angular application compiles into a totally static (client) site, and so it must be deployed as a staticfile web app and not as a Node.js app.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample app using Frederic Lavigne's sample project and deployed it to bluemix. https://github.com/joeydeluca/petstore-client-angular2

Answer (score -1):

There is a new angular2-on-bluemix example created from the official AngularJs 2 tutorial (Tour of Heroes):  https://github.com/nnworkspace/angular2-heroes-bluemix