# How do I deploy Angular 2 starter app on Bluemix?

Tags: angular, ibm-cloud

I checked almost everything in Internet and Stack Overflow. Especially

- [How do I deploy an Angular 2 app on Bluemix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39594760/how-do-i-deploy-an-angular-2-app-on-bluemix)
- https://github.com/nnworkspace/angular2-heroes-bluemix

But none of them really works. Application cannot start. Seems articles above miss some configuration steps. I need just simple starter Angular 2 taken from https://angular.io/guide/quickstart deployed to Bluemix.

Can anybody try and provide exact steps what other configuration needs to be done or what should be installed (except cloud foundry cli, etc. common tools)

Comment: If you're using the CLI you can just `ng build` then deploy the `dist/` directory with the staticfile buildpack. My project here is set up to be `cf push`ed, for example: https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats (specifically see the manifest and the Travis config for CI). Beyond that more detail is needed to diagnose your specific problems.

Comment: I downloaded  https://angular.io/guide/quickstart .. Did npm install then ng build --prod then cf push my-app and it fails to start after deploy. I get the error like "404 Not Found: Requested route ('my-appxxxxx.ng.mybluemix.net') does not exist.". Can you try to deploy exactly Angular starter app and tell me what do you update in the project? I see you added manifest file. What else should be done? Thanks

Comment: That's all, you can see [the commit](https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/9c6dfaf9ab771c17f132f7acf069f9ac5a0291ff); add a manifest that specifies which directory to deploy with which buildpack. Otherwise CF will try to guess, and probably end up running the root directory with the Node buildpack. You should also read the output from the attempted push, which will tell you what it ran and how and what happened as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Than you Jonathan! It works great.. 
Steps to deploy:

```
1. npm install -g @angular/cli
2. ng new my-app4
3. ng serve --open (it works)
4. ng build --prod
5. Copy manifest.yml and .travis.yml (https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats)
6. replace api: https://api.run.pez.pivotal.io to appropriate one in .travis.yml
7. cf login
8. cf push my-app4
```