# Run ng (Angular) commands from bluemix console

Tags: angular, shell, build, ibm-cloud

I want to build my Angular project on the bluemix deploy pipeline. I have tried to create a new build order with a shell script but it just fails. What is the best practice for building the project on Bluemix?

Ex. "ng build --base-href /.../"

Comment: try checking this link hope this link will help you https://github.com/l2fprod/bluemix-hello-angular2

Answer (score 0):

From the project directory, Add `manifest.yml` file. Check for the buildpack below.

```
applications:
 - path: .
  memory: 128M
  instances: 1
  domain: mybluemix.net
  name: your_project_name
  host: your_host_name
  disk_quota: 128M
  buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
```

1. Now, run `ng build` command from the project directory.
2. You should see a dist folder. Go to the dist directory.
3. login bluemix with `cf login`
4. run `cf push <app-name>`

Your app should be deployed in bluemix. Hope this helps.